# Adjacency matrix on the basis of two columns

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I have a data file of two column and want to make a adjacency matrix in the basis of these two column

I have tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df = pd.crosstab(df.Name_A, df.Name_B)
idx = df.columns.union(df.index)
df = df.reindex(index = idx, columns=idx, fill_value=1)
print (df)
```

Output

```
     A  B  C  D
A    0  1  1  0
B    0  0  1  0
C    0  0  0  1
D    0  0  0  0
```

My input example file

```
C_1,C_2
A,B
C,D
A,C
B,C
```

Expected output

```
    A  B  C  D
A   1  1  1  0
B   1  1  1  0
C   1  1  1  1
D   0  0  1  1
```

Comment: ```scipy``` might come handy here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html